# Programmatically adding Label to Windows Form (Length of label?)

Tags: c#, .net, label, windows-forms-designer

In my code, i create a label with the following:

```
Label namelabel = new Label();
namelabel.Location = new Point(13, 13);
namelabel.Text = name;
this.Controls.Add(namelabel);
```

The string called name is defined before this, and has a length of around 50 characters. However, only the first 15 are displayed in the label on my form. I tried messing with the MaximumSize of the label but to no avail.

Comment: FYI: Initializer syntax is much cleaner: `Controls.Add(new Label { Location = new Point(13, 13), AutoSize = true, Text = name });`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding the AutoSize property:

```
namelabel.AutoSize = true;
```

When you place a label on a form with the design editor, this property defaults to true, but if you create the label in code like you did, the default is false.

Answer (score 3):

Try the property AutoSize = true;

[MSDN refs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx)

Another way is using the MeasureString method of the Graphics class

```
Graphics e =  nameLabel.CreateGraphics();
SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
stringSize = e.MeasureString(name, namelabel.Font);
nameLabel.Width = (int)stringSize.Width;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the property `Label.AutoSize` to automatically adjust the width of your label to properly fit all the contents stored in `Label.Text`.

It's worth mentioning that when creating the label using the design editor this property defaults to *true*, but when you programmatically creates a label on your own the property defaults to *false*.

```
namelabel.AutoSize = true;
```

---

Of course you could also manually set the width of your label using something as the below to calculate the required width.

```
Graphics namelabel_g = namelabel.CreateGraphics ();

namelabel.Width = namelabel_g.MeasureString (
  namelabel.Text, namelabel.Font
);
```

---

Documentation regarding the use of `Label.AutoSize` use can be found on *msdn*:

- **[msdn.microsoft.com - Label.AutoSize Property  (System.Windows.Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx)**

---

Documentation regarding `Graphics.MeasureString` can be found here:

- **[msdn.microsoft.com - Graphics.MeasureString Method (String, Font) (System.Drawing)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

```
panel_saved.Controls.Add(
    new Label 
    { 
        Location = new Point(1, 2), 
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(43, 18), 
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, 
        Text = "yourdata" 
    });
```